# how can we avoid showing content of subdomain

Tags: subdomain

I have create a sub domain  like images.domain.com.
accessing it via browser it is listing the content at sub domain.

like

```
    Index of /

   content1/
   content2/
    content3/
```

I dont want to show the content of sub domain.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Please refer : https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/134#code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have directory Indexes enabled (Apache automatically creates a directory listing in such cases). You can workaround this by either placing an empty `index.html` file in the document root of the subdomain (assuming `index.html` is a registered index document).

Or, disable directory Indexes in your `.htaccess` file (in the document root of your subdomain, or even in the document root of your main domain, depending on your file system structure.):

```
Options -Indexes
```

Reference: [Apache Docs - Options Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options):

> **Indexes**
>   If a URL which maps to a directory is requested and there is no DirectoryIndex (e.g., index.html) in that directory, then mod_autoindex will return a formatted listing of the directory.

Comment: in my subdomain there is no .htaccess file available. It is available in main domain

Comment: There is no .htaccess file by default, you need to create it. However, if the main domain points to the parent folder, then you can probably use that (providing you are not relying on this Apache feature on your main site). .htaccess directives in parent folders are inherited. This directive should go at the top.

Comment: I want to creat it in subdomain  and should i put only Options -Indexes to not showing the content

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Yes it is not shoing content. It also protect my images/contents from showing search engines??

Comment: Well, it might not protect your images from being indexed if you are linking to these images on your webpages? And your webpages are crawlable. If you specifically want to prevent indexing you should look at the robots.txt file and the `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header (or the robots meta tag in webpages).